# How to get the iLBC voice length?

Tags: voice

Is it possible to get the iLBC voice length by looking at the file size? Any formula for this?

Does file size directly proportional to the voice length?

Answer (score 0):

Just use NSFileManager:

```
NSFileManager *fm = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
NSDictionary *attrs = [fm attributesOfItemAtPath:recordedFile.path error: NULL];
NSLog(@"File size: %@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lld", [attrs fileSize]]);
```